# BigQuery / SQL aggregate data from one field, many records

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, aggregate

I have the following tables:

```
rooms
    +--------+------------+
    | room_id| room_name  |
    +--------+------------+
    | 1      |  Kitchen   |
    | 2      |  Bedroom   |
    +--------+------------+

room_products
    +--------+------------+
    | room_id| product_id |
    +--------+------------+
    | 1      |    101     |
    | 1      |    102     |
    | 1      |    103     |
    | 1      |    104     |
    | 2      |    105     |
    | 2      |    106     |
    | 2      |    107     |
    +--------+------------+

products
    +------------+--------------+
    | product_id | product_name |
    +------------+--------------+
    | 101        |  Kettle      |
    | 102        |  Toaster     |
    | 103        |  Microwave   |
    | 104        |  Cooker      |
    | 105        |  Bed         |
    | 106        |  Lamp        |
    | 107        |  Clock       |
    +------------+--------------+
```

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| room_name| product_name_aggregated             |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| Kitchen  |  Kettle, Toaster, Microwave, Cooker |
| Bedroom  |  Bed, Lamp, Clock                   |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT r.room_name, STRING_AGG(p.product_name)
FROM rooms r
JOIN room_products rp ON rp.room_id = r.room_id
JOIN products p ON p.product_id = rp.product_id
WHERE r.room_id = 1 OR r.room_id = 2;
```

Think I'm getting all kinds of confused. Would really appreciate any help... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
SELECT r.room_name, STRING_AGG(p.product_name, ',')
FROM rooms r JOIN
     room_products rp
     ON rp.room_id = r.room_id JOIN
     products p
     ON p.product_id = rp.product_id
WHERE r.room_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY r.room_name;
```

The changes are:

- Added a second argument to `STRING_AGG()`.
- Changed the `WHERE` to use `IN` (more convenient; `OR` also works).
- Added `GROUP BY`.

Note that I would recommend `ARRAY_AGG()` rather than `STRING_AGG()` -- arrays are quite useful in BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, and words of encouragement at the top! It's been a rough day... this is a huge help. Thanks.